# fileoutputstream and write method

Tags: android

i m a beginner in android ...i want to know why in my code the fos becoming null here is my main activity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/musics");
            dir.mkdir();
            File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.write("good morning".getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("fos", "null");
            }
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 101);
    }
    tv.setText(fos + "");
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String[] permissions,int[] grantResults) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    if (requestCode == 101 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        try {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/musics");
            dir.mkdir();
            File file = new File(dir, "myData.txt");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.write("good morning".getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fos != null) {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("fos", "null");
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

}
```

and here is the log msg

> 05-25 16:37:06.311 21858-21858/com.example.kalyan.musicextra E/fos: null

Comment: Post ur manifest file plzz

Comment: have added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest and also handled run time permission https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: do you see any exceptions stacktraces? It looks like it is not being created because of excation, that's why it is null

Comment: i have not given run time permission ....thnx pavan

Comment: now i have changed my code like this but not able to create the myData.txt file.....now the fos is not null but myData.txt is not creating

Answer (score 0):

This line throws an exception so your fos variable will be null:

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

You can find the exception in the logcat or add a breakpoint to the catch part and debug it, you will see the exception.